# Where is the per-user salt kept?

Tags: password, encryption

Where does Ubuntu keep the [password salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) for each user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the manual page of [`shadow(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/shadow.5):

> Each line of this file contains 9 fields, separated by colons (“:”), in the following order:
>
> [..]
>     encrypted password
>         Refer to crypt(3) for details on how this string is interpreted.

Alright, let's have a look at [`man 3 crypt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/crypt.3) then. From the notes section:

> [..] So $5$salt$encrypted is an SHA-256 encoded password and $6$salt$encrypted is an SHA-512 encoded one.
>
> "salt"  stands  for  the  up  to 16 characters following "$id$" in the salt.  The encrypted part of the password string is the actual computed password.

So, the salt is stored in the password field of `/etc/shadow` itself. For more details, have a look at the manual page of [crypt(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/crypt.3).

Comment: June 2022: The detailed information about the format of the return value is no longer stored in `man 3 crypt`. It is now stored in `man 5 crypt`.